# How can I fetch the access token using the Grails oauth plugin?

Tags: java, grails, oauth, access-token

I have been trying this for quite a while now. I am able to fetch the request token no problem. But when i try to exchange it for the access token I get the following error:

> 2011-07-17 22:19:19,649 [http-8080-1] ERROR oauth.OauthService  -
>   Unable to fetch access token! (consumerName=google,
>   requestToken=[key:4/Azm6wQDW85iYVmeb4ogCAl70D_89,
>   secret:Zrh9saEDJcgCo83QejOu28sU,
>   authUrl:https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token=4%2FAzm6wQDW85iYVmeb4ogCAl70D_89,
>   isOAuth10a:true])
>   oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication
>   with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error:
>   400 (Bad Request

Here is the code in the controller:

```
   def OauthService
if (session.oauthToken == null) {
        flash.message = "The token could no be retrieved... Please try again"
        redirect(uri:"/")
    }
    def requestToken = OauthService.fetchRequestToken('google')
    def accessToken = OauthService.fetchAccessToken('google', requestToken)
```

I have been playing about with it but it never seems to work any way I do it. Has anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [OAuth plugin docs](http://www.grails.org/plugin/oauth), it mentions that some Google APIs require the `scope` attribute to be set in the OAuth config (in `Config.groovy`).  Might be worth double-checking, considering the Google server is returning `400 Bad Request`.

Also, enabling debug logging for the `grails.app.service.org.grails.plugins.oauth` and `grails.app.controller.org.grails.plugins.oauth` packages might provide some more clues.